# SHOW TABLES and MYSQL_NUM_ROWS

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-num-rows

I have just noticed that where mysql_num_rows should return the number of rows returned for either SELECT or SHOW commands, returns 0 for SHOW TABLE command specifically.

Instead it shows the affected rows count instead of the num rows.

Can anyone please tell me if this is a bug or if am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 3):

`SHOW TABLE` command is used to Show you table name in your database . On the other hand , `mysql_num_rows` is used to count how many result got from your query. This query is depend on your requirement basis ...

Answer (score 1):

As stated on [the PHP documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php):

> Retrieves the number of rows from a result set. This command is only
>   valid for statements like SELECT or SHOW that return an actual result
>   set.

My guess is that `SHOW TABLES` is not a technical query that would produce the type of result set that `mysql_num_rows` enumerates.

Answer (score 1):

These "helper" functions (such as `SHOW`, `EXPLAIN`, `DESCRIBE` etc.) won't let you *issue* their results like you would in a regular table.

But if you're looking for how you can do this, for `SHOW TABLES` you can do

```
SELECT `table_name` FROM `information_schema`.`tables`
WHERE `table_schema`=DATABASE()
-- DATABASE() selects current database name
-- you can use the name of any database as a string instead
```

So basically you can use the `information_schema` database to get that information.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in mysql, fixed it with the update.